# Is there any way to get iPhone app notification to Mac computer?

Tags: macos, ios, mac, notifications

When an iPhone app gets a notification, I don't want to go heads down and check the phone.  Is there any way to get that notification on my Mac instead?

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no native way to do this, but there are a couple of ways to do this with 3rd party apps:

- [Notifyr](http://getnotifyr.com/) ($4).  This will allow you to receive push notifications from any app on your iOS device with your Mac.  There are some base system requirements, so thee the web page for full details.
  (Update: Notifyr is no longer available in the App Store and its website is obsolete.)
- [ForwardNotifier](https://github.com/Greg0109/ForwardNotifier) (Free).  This requires you to jailbreak your phone but you will be able to get your push notification on macOS, Windows, and Linux.

Comment: Notifyr didn't work on my catalina(Notifyr requires Bluetooth 4.0, which is not supported on this Mac.)

I'll try using ForwardNotifier ,Thank you

Comment: Notifyr seems to be discontinued and removed from App Store :(